# get the value of the selected option from the drop down

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a newbie to angular. I have a bootstrap drop-down and i need to get the value of the selected option from that dropdown. thanks in advance.

```js
  FacultyorStudent_Data: Array<string> = ['Faculty/Coach','Student']
  selected_FacultyorStudent: string = this.FacultyorStudent_Data[0];
  
  SelectFacultyorStudent(FnS){
   
    console.log(FnS)
  }
```

```html
  <div class="text-center" id="perf-type">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{selected_FacultyorStudent}}&nbsp; Insights<i
        class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let item of FacultyorStudent_Data; let i = index;"
        [ngClass]="{'bg-selected-subject': selected_FacultyorStudent==item}"
        (click)="SelectFacultyorStudent(FnS)">
        {{item}}</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `item` as an argument of `SelectFacultyorStudent` like `(click)="SelectFacultyorStudent(item)`

Answer (score 1):

pass item instead of fns in html file

```
<div class="text-center" id="perf-type">
        <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{selected_FacultyorStudent}}&nbsp; Insights<i
            class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li *ngFor="let item of FacultyorStudent_Data; let i = index;"
            [ngClass]="{'bg-selected-subject': selected_FacultyorStudent==item}"
            (click)="SelectFacultyorStudent(item)">
            {{item}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>


FacultyorStudent_Data: Array<string> = ['Faculty/Coach','Student']
  selected_FacultyorStudent: string = this.FacultyorStudent_Data[0];

  SelectFacultyorStudent(FnS){

    console.log(FnS)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I have passed item instead of an FnS from your HTML. And Received the value in TS file and assign the value to the **selected_FacultyorStudent** this variable.

```
 <div class="text-center" id="perf-type">
<div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{selected_FacultyorStudent}}&nbsp; Insights<i
    class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li *ngFor="let item of FacultyorStudent_Data; let i = index;"
    [ngClass]="{'bg-selected-subject': selected_FacultyorStudent==item}"
    (click)="SelectFacultyorStudent(item)">
    {{item}}</li>

</ul>
```

```
  FacultyorStudent_Data: Array<string> = ['Faculty/Coach','Student']
  selected_FacultyorStudent: string = this.FacultyorStudent_Data[0];

  SelectFacultyorStudent(FnS){
   this.selected_FacultyorStudent = FnS;
    console.log(FnS)
  }
```